# Nice easy way of capitalizing names such as "o'sullivan"?

Tags: php

Take two strings:

```
"o'sulLivAn"
"doUble-baRrel"
```

Desired result:

```
"O'Sullivan"
"Double-Barrel"
```

I thought `ucwords(strtolower($str))` might do the trick but it treats the strings as a single word.

I know I can `explode`, or rather `preg_split` the string and then capitalize the parts and put it back together again, but I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing it?

Usually with PHP and this sort of thing there tends to be a function hiding away somewhere that'd be useful but isn't obvious or well known.

Comment: This is a very hard problem due to the tremendous variations in how names are capitalized.  If you really want to just capitalize after a non-alpha character, then splitting and reassembling is probably the easiest to code.  

However consider input like "vanhalen" or "thooft", which could be "VanHalen" and "tHooft", or "vanHalen".  What do you do with "vandermies", which could validly be "VanDerMies", or "vanDerMies"?  Is this part of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Jim Fortunately not! If the user enters a string in that way it'll have to be treated as they entered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no php function to do this.

Here's a one-liner with no loop (kinda)

```
$str1 = "double-barrel";
$str2 = "o'sulLivAn";


function my_ucase( $str, $chars="-'" ) {
    return implode(array_map( 'ucwords', array_map( 'strtolower', preg_split( "~([".$chars."])~", $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE ))));
}

echo my_ucase($str1);
echo my_ucase($str2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use preg_replace_callback() here:

```
function upcaseLetters(string $line): string {
    return preg_replace_callback('#^[\w]|[\W][\w]#', function ($match) {    
        return strtoupper($match[0]);
    }, strtolower($line));
}
```

Usage Example:

```
$lines = [
    "o'sulLivAn",
    "doUble-baRrel",
];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo upcaseLetters($line), "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/l8BKF

Outputs:

```
O'Sullivan
Double-Barrel
```

Reference:

- https://php.net/preg_replace_callback

Comment: ^1 this is simpler to understand than the chosen answer. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the `e` modifier (deprecated in 2016):

```
preg_replace('!(^|\W)[a-z]!e', "strtoupper('\\0')", strtolower($text));
```

Comment: yes, this is the way to go. The regexp can be simplified to `\b[a-z]`